# ngx-graph : Build fails

Tags: angular, ngx-graph

I have used **ngx-graph** to implement visualization of a DAG. It works perfectly during development and throws no errors. While in a deployed build, it stacks up errors in the console.

[image]

I guess it is looking for some provider but none is described in the package or demo. Here's my *app.module.ts* file :

```
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { NgxGraphModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-graph'
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'
...
imports: [
    ...,
    NgxChartsModule,
    NgxGraphModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
]
```

Answer (score 1):

We also had this problem with AOT compilation using `ngx-graph` with Angular 7 and didn't want to disable AOT compilation.

It seems that previous versions of `ngx-graph` and `ngx-charts` are working correctly with AOT compilation.

We have tried with

```
"@swimlane/ngx-graph": "5.5.0"

"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "8.1.0"
```

and it is working fine

More info in this [issue](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/issues/105#issuecomment-446646360)

Answer (score 1):

The error was caused because **ngx-graph** had dependency on **ngx-charts** in earlier versions. They fixed this in version **6.0.0+** and the dependency has been removed.